# EXP function Excel

Tags: excel, exp

I'm trying to get this into excel: e^(-(2.2/9.58)^2)
According to my graphical calculator AND wolfram alpha this should give: 0.9486

However when I type it in excel with the following formula: =EXP(-(2.2/9.58)^2) I get 1.054

I've tried multiple different things but I still can't get the right answer out of it. What am I doing wrong with the formula in Excel??

Answer (score 1):

Excel seems to mess up the brackets and does some distribution on its own. Very odd.

`=EXP(-((2,2/9,58)^2))` should work

Answer (score 1):

By way of some explanation, in Excel (as conventional) the negation operator has [precedence](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculation-operators-and-precedence-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a) over exponentiation. So:

```
=EXP(-(2.2/9.58)^2)
```

is treated just as:

```
=EXP((-2.2/9.58)^2)
```

or

```
=EXP(0.052737)
```

would be, hence resulting in `1.05415`. Whereas:

```
=EXP(-0.052737)
```

is `0.948629`.

Comment: It is good you can get into such details because, honestly, in these days a developer is usually buried under a huge learning curve of new languages, frameworks, etc. and rarely gets the time to 'get back to basics'.